# Замена значений в csv. Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Импортирую ответ сервера в csv, а потом открываю его как `DataFrame`.
Проблема в том, что в файл нулевые значения пишутся как `'--'`, из-за чего у меня вылезает ошибка соответствия данных.

Насколько я понял, проще будет как-то открывать CSV и менять эти символы на 0.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как быть :)
а может и вовсе это как-то реализовать с помощью DataFrame

```
file = open("cashe.txt", "w")
file.write(data)
file.close()


f = DataFrame.from_csv("cashe.txt",header=1, sep='  ', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой (__«почему этот код не работает?»__) должны включать желаемое поведение, _конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код_ для её воспроизведения __прямо в вопросе__. Вопросы __без явного описания проблемы__ бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ["Что делать с ответами на вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

воспроизводимый пример CSV данных:

```
A   B   C
1   --  3
4   5   6
7   --  9
```

при попытке прочесть такие данные столбец `B` будет содержать строки вместо чисел:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\1.tsv', delim_whitespace=True)

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   A   B  C
0  1  --  3
1  4   5  6
2  7  --  9

In [6]: df.dtypes
Out[6]:
A     int64
B    object   # <--- NOTE!
C     int64
dtype: object
```

используйте параметр `na_values=['--']`, чтобы указать `pd.read_csv()`, что `NaN` у вас представлены в виде `--`:

```
In [7]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\1.tsv', delim_whitespace=True, na_values=['--'])

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   A    B  C
0  1  NaN  3
1  4  5.0  6
2  7  NaN  9

In [9]: df.dtypes
Out[9]:
A      int64
B    float64   # <--- NOTE!
C      int64
dtype: object
```

теперь можно легко заполнить `NaN` нулем:

```
In [15]: df['B'] = df['B'].fillna(0)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   A    B  C
0  1  0.0  3
1  4  5.0  6
2  7  0.0  9
```

---

Отступление: [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) подробно описано как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?